# PHP Arrays Accessing title name of array object

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the title name of an array object.

For example I have

```
$results[0]['page']
$results[0]['title']
```

I was wondering if I could use a for loop to loop through the $results[0] array and get the 'page' and 'title' names and insert them into a new array?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($results[0] as $key=>$value) {
     //Your key will be page and title, and then the value will be in value
}
```

More information on [the PHP documentation for `foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just use [array_keys()](http://php.net/array_keys) to turn the assoc indexes into a new array automatically.